# javascript create and append element function not work

Tags: javascript

this is my javascript function :

```
function createLink (){
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "#";
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("This is dynamic link");
    link.appendChild(linkText);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
}
```

window.onload = createLink;

but i am not get any result from this. any one know, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5):

What you have works, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/8qesG/). Make sure that whenever you're running this isn't *after* `window.onload` has already fired, otherwise it won't run.

Also, make sure something else isn't stealing the `onload` event, and setting the handler to something other than `createLink`, for example a `window.onload = otherFunction` later down the line.